# How to replace Spring boot's default logback config from a library?

Tags: spring-boot, logging, logback

I am building a spring-boot starter to automatically configure logback for our delivery teams. Basically, I ship a set of preconfigured logback appenders which can be enabled and configured through properties.

Goals are:

- When starter is added to dependencies, logback is automatically configured. Appenders behaviour can be tweaked (ex. dev VS prod) using regular properties and logger levels set using `logging.level`. I expect that most users will want and do.
- It is possible to augment default behaviour by providing your own `logback(-spring)?.xml`. You have to include starter's logback configuration file(s).
- It is possible to completely ignore starter configuration by providing your own logback configuration file.

My issue is that I haven't found a *clean* way to implement a such library. My current solution is to register an application listener which runs just before  `LoggingApplicationListener`. If `logging.config` is not set and no logback configuration file is found, `logging.config` is set to library's configuration file. Otherwise, it does nothing.

Is there any less hacky way to do that?

Comment: Hi Clement, did you find a good solution for this?

Comment: I ended up registering an ApplicationListener that run just before LoggingApplicationListener and set a default config if user hasn't supplied one. Not nice but did the job. I just dumped the code here: https://gist.github.com/cykl/c052a3f9c64d58a56e383319be2a8d52. Wrote this code in 2018, maybe something better has been added to Spring since.

Answer (score 0):

it is possible to have your own logback-spring.xml file in src/main/resources. As a working sample, take a pic here which is with custom appender for JSON log output:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration scan="true" scanPeriod="10 seconds">
  <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml"/>
  <springProperty scope="context" name="jsonFile" source="logging.json.file"/>
  <springProperty scope="context" name="jsonLevel" source="logging.json.level"/>
  <springProperty scope="context" name="jsonSize" source="logging.json.size"/>

  <appender name="jsonAppender" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <File>${jsonFile}</File>
    <encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LogstashEncoder"/>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy">
      <maxIndex>1</maxIndex>
      <fileNamePattern>${jsonFile}.%i</fileNamePattern>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <triggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
      <MaxFileSize>${jsonSize}</MaxFileSize>
    </triggeringPolicy>
  </appender>
  <root level="${jsonLevel}">
    <appender-ref ref="jsonAppender"/>
  </root>
</configuration>
```

Comment: If a **library** provides a `logback-spring.xml` in classpath it will conflict (ie. one or another will be used depending on classpath order) with the application provided one (if any). Thus, it does not suit my 2nd and 3rd requirements. Am I missing something ?

Comment: for 2nd and 3rd do you need to completely "get rid of" default start config ?

Comment: judging from our code btw, I see that we still have both logging and never tought about "disableing" deafult one

Comment: Basically, I want to do exactly whatSpring boot does: come with an opinionated view (1st requirement), allow composition if I am almost right but application needs more (2nd requirement, exactly what you do by including Spring's `base.xml`, I provide my own) and disappear if I'm wrong (3rd requirement, what you would do by dropping the `include` statement from your conf file). The issue being that Spring Boot `LoggingSystem` does exactly that but has no extension point allowing to replace its configuration with yours. Meaning you end up hacking around.